# Better way to return any match in a python regex search?

Tags: python, regex, search

I'm running a simple regex search for two criteria `Profile` and `BuildDate`.
I want to cover the possibility that I will either find both, one, or no results and return as much information as possible. Here is how I've written it, but I am wondering if there is a more Pythonic way?

```
    p = re.search(r'Profile\t+(\w+)',s)
    d = re.search(r'BuildDate\t+([A-z0-9-]+)',s)

    # Return whatever you can find. 
    if p is None and d is None:
        return (None, None)
    elif p is None:
        return (None, d.group(1))
    elif d is None:
        return (p.group(1), None)
    else:
        return (p.group(1),d.group(1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p = re.search(r'Profile\t+(\w+)',s)
d = re.search(r'BuildDate\t+([A-z0-9-]+)',s)

return (p.group(1) if p is not None else None,
        d.group(1) if d is not None else None)
```

Also this way:

```
return (p and p.group(1), d and d.group(1))
```

which is less verbose, but a little bit more obscure.

Comment: Very elegant and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!